# Do I have to download a model to create a human being?

Tags: modeling

This will be my first animation and I don't know what I have to do to create a human being. 
I think I have to download a model. Can you tell me a secure and free website?  Do I have to create the bones, face, cloths after the model?  Can you tell me the steps that I have to follow to create an animation please?

Comment: I suggest learning to model your own. reliance on make-human or other software develops skills that give you model like [this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?161266-Jazz-Jackrabbit-(free-rigged-textured-animated-model)-NEW-LOGIC&p=2865482&viewfull=1#post2865482) because your modeling skills will never improve. Being a self sustained modeler is fun and you can really gain valuable experience.

Comment: @VincentScalia do you know any good source of tutorials for human modelling? I've used google and they all seem to use models.

Comment: Start with basic modeling. Not just humans. If I get around to it later today, I can put a tut together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best to learn the long ways before taking the shortcuts. In your case, don't try to start by using something like MakeHuman. Learn to do it with traditional modeling first, and then look at the short cuts.

Some of the most common ways to model a human are Sculpting, Box modeling, and Poly modeling.

Sculpting is exactly that, sculpting. It's really good for organic modeling. Most of the time, when people use sculpting to model a character, they'll use dynamic topology which adds resolution to a mesh in the area that you're sculpting in. Sculpting usually requires a level of retopology, where the sculpted mesh is remodeled using the original as a guide to create a cleaner mesh.

Box modeling is probably the easiest to do. It usually works by starting with a cube and adding a mirror modifier on it so that only half of the model has to be modeled. You then start extruding portions of the cube to form different parts of the head and body. Box modeling also will usually require retopology, as the faces won't usually follow the forms of the mesh properly.

Polymodeling is probably the hardest out of all of the options, but is also the only one that doesn't require retopology. It works by manually extruding edges to form the different parts of the mesh. It's difficult because you're working on making the mesh form right, and getting the topology right at the same time.

Out of the three of those, I would most recommend Sculpting, because it's the most organic and creative way to work, and let's you completely forget about your topology.

Now, since you did want to know where you could go to get human characters, I'll recommend that you head over to [Blendswap](http://www.blendswap.com/). The models are all free, and can be used under different licenses. You might even be able to find a decent one that is already rigged.

Comment: great minds think alike... Apparently ours do too.

Comment: @VincentScalia to an extent :)

Answer (score 2):

Makehuman is indeed an excellent tool.
To answer the second part of your question, and complete the precedent answer, concerning animation, you can import the model into blender by activating the mxh import plugin https://thomasmakehuman.wordpress.com/mhx2-documentation/import-into-blender/
Then, you can import .bhv mocap datas founded on the net (a lot of free ressources are availables) :

- mocap.web.fh-koeln.de/webgl-search.php

(I can't put more than 2 links on this site because of my reputation wich is still too low, but a google search will do the job)

You then need to add the addon called MakeWalk, wich you can find on the makehuman site (same pb with the url, but you can find it on the thomasmakehuman site already listed). This will allow you to load and retarget your downloaded bhv files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open source software, MakeHuman for the starters. It can create customized, rigged human model, which can be imported into Blender.
http://www.makehuman.org/